# SignalR unsupported server version 1.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin.ios, signalr, signalr-hub

When I'm trying to connect to my server from Xamarin.iOS client I got this error from response:

```
'You are using a version of the client that isn't compatible with the server. Client version 1.4, server version 1.0.'
```

I have updated all SignalR packages both on client and server, so there is have SignalR.Client v2.2.0 on client and SignalR.Core v2.2.0 on server, but I still have this error

Comment: Only possibility: You're still referencing the old assemblies.

Comment: @rdoubleui thanks for response, well, ok, I'll recheck it again today

Comment: @rdoubleui hi! I checked bin folder, that will be deployed to server, but SignalR.Core there is 2.2.0 and same in Client - 2.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, yes, I've just removed all packages and installed throw NuGet one by one, that helped me. Didn't find where I broke references, sorry.